# Windows 7 remote desktop connection conflict with FTP Serve?

Tags: windows

Today I was connecting to another computer using Windows 7 remote desktop connection and I just setted up a IIS FTP server on this computer. Then I changed the inbound rule of windows 7 firewall to allow FTP service. After finishing that, I lost connection with the computer and could not connect to it using Remote Desktop Connection. Why will this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know another solution for this problem on OnlineVNC basis. OnlineVNC it is a remote desktop with 
embeded FTP server inside which does not conflict each other. Very easy to set up and fast. Maybe it will be help full for you.
http://www.onlinevnc.com/support/configuring-ftp-based-file-transfer.html